# With Amazon Route 53 use own domain name for EC2 instance

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

This should be incredibly obvious, but I can't seem to work out how to do it.

I have an [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance running. I can see the 'Public DNS' (hostname) of my instance.

I have set up a [Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) 'hosted zone' for my domain, and changed the name servers with the registrar.

But how (using the AWS Management Console) do I actually link them, so my domain maps to my instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create an A record to the Elastic IP that is (should be!) attached to your instance.

If you're using an Elastic Load Balancer, you create an ALIAS record to it instead.